# Using more than one, "for x in y" in the same row. Syntax issue

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7, syntax-error

What I want to do is simple:

```
collection = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[]}
values = [1,2,3]
```

I want to make a function that produces the following: (append the values into the list element of the dictionary, the `dic` and the `list` are the same length)

```
{'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[3]}
```

This is simple enough and I can do it using, a couple of  `for x in`. But I want to do this in one line. (using two loops in the same line) and I can not get the syntax to work.

I have tried some things similar to this, but they all result in syntax error:

```
collection[c].append(value), for c in d.iteritems(), for value in values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do on one line. You can create a new dictionary on one line though:

```
{k: collection[k] + [v] for k, v in zip(collection.keys(), values)}
```

Result:

```
>>> collection = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[]}
>>> values = [1,2,3]
>>> {k: collection[k] + [v] for k, v in zip(collection.keys(), values)}
{'a': [1], 'c': [2], 'b': [3]}
```

This is called a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays). Like a list comprehension and a generator expression, you *can* use multiple loops in one of those, but you don't need one here. `zip()` will pair up the keys from `collection` with the integers from `values`.

To modify a `dict` in-place, you'll have to use 2 lines at least:

```
for k, v in zip(collection.keys(), values):
    collection[k].append(v)
```

Python does accept that on one line, but that goes against just about every styleguide I can look up for you:

```
for k, v in zip(collection.keys(), values): collection[k].append(v)
```

Python throws a syntax error because it interprets your line as a tuple of expressions (the commas make it a tuple), and two of your expressions are `for` statements, which cannot be used in an expression.